# How should I reload a ball?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I am making an angry bird type 2d game using Unity and C#. After I throw the ball from catapult, I have no idea on reloading the ball. Then I use SceneAsync to reload the ball but it is the worst thing I've ever made since I can't make the other sprite objects to continue their movents after the ball is thrown. So what code should I use to reload the balls after throwing?

Comment: Could you post the code you're currently using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Instantiate method that unity provides for instantiating new gameobjects. Just keep a static reference for initial position like:

```
private static Vector3 initialPosition = new Vector3(10, 10, 0) //The values are dummy
```

And also keep a reference for the ball's prefab:

```
public Gameobject ballPrefab; //Drag the ball prefab in the editor
```

And finally when it comes to instantiate:

```
Gameobject newBall = Instantiate (ballPrefab, initialPosition, Quaternion.identity) as Gameobject;
```

Now the newBall will appear in the scene with the position you set with "initialPositon". And the newBall variable keeps reference for the new object that you have instantiated

Comment: How can I create prefab for the ball?

Comment: Just drag the ball object you created from the hierarchy, to the assets folder. Then it will become a prefabbed object. Remember: you need to drag prefab to the script's ballPrefab slot, not the gameobject from the hierarchy. Google these if you want to learn more "prefabbing an object", "Instantiating a prefab".

Comment: Thanks @Tolga! But after I add it,it says  springjoint2d is missing..but I added it with..new ball.add Component<Springjoint2d>();

Comment: Consider adding the joint manually in the inspector. That is a different problem and I cannot debug it with the comments since I cannot see your code.